# Building Qt C++ project with Ogre3D for Android platform under Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: android, qt, ubuntu, ogre

I have carried out the correct Build and Run for "Desktop Mode", and now I'm trying to deploy the same to Android. While building, I get the following error:

> "OGRE development package not found".

What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

It can be helpfull to install "libogre dev" package (try install "libogre" too).